# Запретить вопросы характера "Помогите перевести код с jQuery на чистый JS"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

На ruSo, so и остальных so, есть множество вопросов по типу: "Помогите перевести код с jQuery на чистый JS". Я понимаю что новички хотят переучиться на чистый JS, или по ТЗ нужен чистый JS, но Stackoverflow (внимание цитата) "не бюро переводов" (конец цитаты), я полностью согласен с этим, и как по мне, авторов таких вопросов нужно посылать на *документацию*, или на [GitHub страницу YouMightNotNeedjQuery](https://github.com/HubSpot/YouMightNotNeedjQuery) или сайт [youmightnotneedjquery.com](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), к тому же уже на данный момент множество пользователей сливают такие "вопросы" на дно Stackoverflow, хотелось бы узнать мнение пользователей, как они считают, стоит ли удалять такие вопросы или, таким вопросам стоит существовать и я не прав.(Точку зрения аргументировать)

Comment: А что значит "запретить"?

Comment: Тут сколько людей, столько и мнений. Поэтому лучше (особенно сейчас) не нагнетать и поменьше запрещать. В общем, не нравится вопрос -- пройди мимо

Comment: Просьбы перевести кусок кода уже и так запрещены по причине «вопрос слишком общий» aka «необходимо конкретизировать». Конкретные же вопросы про какую-то одну конкретную фичу вполне онтопик

Comment: @АлексейШиманский блокировать или указать в правилах, что такие вопросы запрещены.

Comment: @ΝNL993 а кто-то читает правила? Абсолюнто никто..

Comment: @ΝNL993 .а блокировать как? Как вычислять такие вопросы?

Comment: Спасибо всем кто откликнулся на моё предложение, почитав ваши комментарии в прицепе я с вами согласен, не стоит ещё больше нагружать правила.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Для начала я читаю правила, а блокировать можно по старинке, тревогой.

Comment: @ΝNL993 вы читаете, остальные 99% пришедших - нет  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   ....... а блокировать по-старинке - ну этого никто не отнимал пока. Если кажется что вопрос оффтоп - нажимаем кнопочку "Закрыть вопорс" или "Тревога"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В будущем так и буду делать, ещё раз спасибо, что откликнулись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимости в данном конкретном запрете нет, как и в других аналогичных, т.к. они уже входят в категорию закрытия «вопрос слишком общий» (и *Stackoverflow - "не бюро переводов"*). Если же вопрос не о простынке кода, а вполне конкретен - всё ок.

Если кажется, что вопрос не по теме - голосуйте за закрытие или ставьте тревогу, а если вопрос на ваш взгляд *"не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы"* - ставьте ему минус.